# MongoDB /AWS documentdb index utilization with and without limit

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aws-documentdb

Here is my index:

`db.foobar.createIndex( { 'foo' : -1, 'bar' : 1, 'baz' : 1 }, { background : true, name : 'foobar_idx' } );`

Now I would expect that a query that sorts by `foo` and filters on `bar` would use the index. And it does, ***if*** you specify a limit:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.foobar.find( { 'bar' : 'xyz' }, { 'some.field' : 1 } ).sort( { 'foo' : -1 } ).limit(1000).explain()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "foobardb",
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "SUBSCAN",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "LIMIT_SKIP",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "indexName" : "foobar_idx",
                                        "direction" : "forward"
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

But if you don't specify a limit, or if the limit is very high, it does not want to use the index:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.foobar.find( { 'bar' : 'xyz' }, { 'some.field' : 1 } ).sort( { 'foo' : -1 } ).explain()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "foobardb",
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "SUBSCAN",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "foo" : -1
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN"
                                }
                        }
           },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Even if I provide a hint to use the index it won't use it.

Why on earth does it not use the darn index?

Answer (score 2):

To understand this behavior you have to consider how the index is constructed, and how it is searched.

Consider a collection containing these 10 documents:

```
{"foo" : 9, "bar" : "A", "baz" : "Y" }
{"foo" : 2, "bar" : "B", "baz" : "Y" }
{"foo" : 5, "bar" : "A", "baz" : "Z" }
{"foo" : 0, "bar" : "A", "baz" : "Y" }
{"foo" : 6, "bar" : "A", "baz" : "X" }
{"foo" : 4, "bar" : "B", "baz" : "Y" }
{"foo" : 8, "bar" : "A", "baz" : "Z" }
{"foo" : 1, "bar" : "A", "baz" : "Y" }
{"foo" : 7, "bar" : "B", "baz" : "Z" }
{"foo" : 3, "bar" : "B", "baz" : "X" }
```

If we define an index on `{foo:1, bar:1, baz:1}` the index will contain these pairs:

```
0|A|Y => 3
1|A|Y => 7
2|B|Y => 1
3|B|X => 9
4|B|Y => 5
5|A|Z => 2
6|A|X => 4
7|B|Z => 8
8|A|Z => 6
9|A|Y => 0
```

**Equality query**

If we then query on `{foo:5, bar:"A"}`, the query executor can begin scanning at the first matching value, `5|A|Z`.  In this case it is the only matching value, so it ends there.

**Ranged query**

If we then query on `{foo: {$lt:5}, bar:"A"}`, it will scan the index for `foo` values in the range `[MinKey(),5)`, and for each value of `foo` encountered it will conduct a scan for matching values of `bar`.  This means that instead of scanning a single range of the index, it will need to scan 5 ranges to find the 2 matches.

**Query + Sort**

If we query on on `{bar: "A"}` and sort by `{foo:1}`, if the query executor tried to use this index, it would need to examine every entry in the index, and for each value of `foo` conduct a scan for matching values of `bar`.  For this example, that means 10 ranges.

**Query Planning**

When a query shape is first seen, the query planner identifies the different ways it might run the query, and runs a test.  Each plan is run for a short time, and the plan that produces the most results with the least amount of work is selected.

In the case of `db.foobar.find({bar:"A"}).sort({foo:1})`, our test scenario has 2 possible plans:

**Plan A: index scan**

- load the index from disk, if not already in the cache
- scan 10 index ranges
- load 6 documents from disk, if not already in the cache

**Plan B: collection scan**

- load 10 documents from disk, if not already in the cache
- sort in memory

Depending on what is already in the cache, the selection here is a bit of a toss up.

**Using a limit**

When you introduce a smallish limit, such as `db.foobar.find({bar:"A"}).sort({foo:1}).limit(2)`, they query is able to terminate early when using the index that finds the documents already in sorted order. In this case, the possible plans look like:

**Plan A: index scan**

- load the index from disk, if not already in the cache
- scan 2 index ranges
- load 2 documents from disk, if not already in the cache

**Plan B: collection scan**

- load 10 documents from disk, if not already in the cache
- sort in memory
- limit to 2 documents

It should be fairly obvious that the index scan will perform better in this case.

With larger limits this is not so obvious.  Consider `db.foobar.find({bar:"A"}).sort({foo:1}).limit(5)`, for this query the possible plans are:

**Plan A: index scan**

- load the index from disk, if not already in the cache
- scan 9 index ranges
- load 5 documents from disk, if not already in the cache

**Plan B: collection scan**

- load 10 documents from disk, if not already in the cache
- sort in memory
- limit to 5 documents

This is almost back to the same plans as the unlimited case.

**A better index**

When building indexes in MongoDB, consider how you plan to query the data, and order the keys in the index according to equality-sort-range.  This means list the fields you will be matching exactly, then the fields for sorting, and then any other fields.

For our example, an index on `{bar:1, foo:1, baz:1}` would contain the pairs:

```
A|0|Y => 3
A|1|Y => 7
A|5|Z => 2
A|6|X => 4
A|8|Z => 6
A|9|Y => 0
B|2|Y => 1
B|3|X => 9
B|4|Y => 5
B|7|Z => 8
```

And the sorted query `db.foobar.find({bar:"A"}).sort({foo:1})` would have another possible plan:

**Plan C: index scan**

- scan a single range of the `{bar:1, foo:1, baz:1}` index
- fetch 6 documents from disk, if not already in cache

This plan should outperform all of the other possibilities by a significant margin, and applying a limit reduces the work done by this plan, so it should still be chosen.

Comment: Thank you, I am not clear what the numbers in your index examples point to though: `B|2|Y => 1` what does the 1 represent? Also my documents are multiple megabytes each and there are millions of them so I don't see how doing a collscan is ever a better plan if everything it needs to sort and filter are in the index.

Comment: The 1 represents the internal document identifier, in this case I just numbered the original 10 documents in the order they appear.

Answer (score 0):

If an index is insufficiently selective, a table scan may be more efficient than an index scan. The storage system affects the decision also (spinning disk favors table scan, SSD favors index scan).